# How to find the minimum order for a low pass filter with different gain levels

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter

I have the following for a filter with passbands having different gain levels, in this case I set the order arbitrarily to 100. Is there a way to find the minimum order that still satisfies the specifications?

```
fpts = [0 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.52 1]; %frequency points
mval = [0.3 0.3 1.0 1.0 0.7 0.7]; %magnitudes of frequency components
n = 100;
b = fir2(n,fpts,mval); %design the FIR filter
[h,omega] = freqz(b,1,512); %get the response
plot(omega/pi,abs(h));grid; %plot the response
xlabel('\omega/\pi'); ylabel('Magnitude');
```

[image: Magnitude res]

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "satisfy the specifications". But in general there is no way to know the minimum order in advance. There are some heuristic formulas such as the one used in Matlab's `firpmord.m`.

Comment: On top of what Matt said, you will be restricted to the narrowest transition width out of the all possible ones. Often what is done for such critical requirements is to generate a filter, then check whether the t.w. is larger or smaller, then recalculate with an adjusted order, check again, rinse and repeat. You'll still have the same limitation.

Answer (score 1):

> ... that still satisfies the specifications?

First you need a complete set of specifications that can be quantitatively verified. That typically includes max allowable deviation from the target by frequency or by band either my RMS deviation, peak deviation, max absolute deviation, min attenuation for stopbands, etc. It may also include max latency, max phase or group delay distortions, causality, etc.

All of these depend heavily on your specific application and this is often the most tricky part of filter design.

> Is there a way to find the minimum order ... ?

That can easily be done. Once you have a complete specification, you can simply try different orders and check which one meets your requirements. A binary search converges very quickly and can be done automatically.

Sometimes you might not like the answer. In this case you may have to iterate the specifications. Relax some constraints and see what that does to your filter order (or other undesirable properties). This way you  find the best trade off between the filter than you want and the filter that you can afford or trade off between conflicting requirements. That's often the real "art" of filter design.